# NativeScript Tab View Property binding tabItem error

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to implement a TabView with Angular `2.0.1`, NativeScript `2.3.0`. I follow this official guide [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/cookbook/tab-view-ng), but run into an issue below.

```
<TabView #tabview>
        [ERROR ->]<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Profile'}" >
          <ListView [items]='items'>
            <template let-i"): LoginComponent@17:4
    Property binding tabItem not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "directives" section. ("
          </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
        [ERROR ->]<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Stats'}">
          <Label text="Second tab item"></Label>
        </StackLay"): LoginComponent@24:4
    Property binding tabItem not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "directives" section. ("
          <Label text="Second tab item"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        [ERROR ->]<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Settings'}">
          <Label text="Third tab item"></Label>
```

The error I got from the compiler is

```
Property binding tabItem not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "directives" section.
```

I thought all of **nativescript directives** have been included by default, ex: `Button`, `TextField`, etc. Is `*tabItem` a special directive that I need to import manually?

By the way, What I really want to do, is to have a TabView stick at the bottom of the phone, like Dock with a few tabs, exactly like Facebook mobile app dock. Can someone post a code snippet?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce issues, while testing the example from the article on both Android and iOS. regarding to that it will help if you could share the code, where you are using the TabView component. At this point for Android the Tabs of the TabView wiil always be at the top and their position could not be changed. For your purpose you could use SegmentedBar and to control manually the visibility of the Layouts - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/segmented-bar/segmented-bar-views .

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you import `NativeScriptModule` in your Angular `@NgModule`:

```
import { NativeScriptModule } from 'nativescript-angular/platform';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptModule, ...]
})
```

Answer is late but hope it help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked over 2 years ago, but I ran into this error today and here's how I ended up fixing it. I use a structure where all pages are imported by a `PageModule`, and that `PageModule` is then imported by the `AppModule`. The issue at hand: `PageModule` doesn't know about the `NativeScriptModule`. If you add `NativeScriptModule` to the `import` array of your `PageModule` (or whatever other module you're using, could be for importing Components or anything else), it'll fix the problem.

```
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
// Module declaration, not important
imports = [
    // Other imports
    NativeScriptModule
],
```

Comment: For lazy loading, one should try to use NativeScriptCommonModule instead, because NativeScriptModule must have already been imported into the AppModule.

Answer (score 0):

The common module is all you need to import, it's responsible for the tabViews and all it's child property and element.

```
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from 'nativescript-angular/common';
```

don't forget to mount in your import.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptCommonModule, ...]
})
```